# Why isn’t mean of errors in the PRF = 0?

Tags: probability, self-study, least-squares, sample, unbiased-estimator

[image]

The image attached contains a part of derivation from my [Basic Econometrics](http://amzn.to/2yLwlEF) text book. ( deriving the estimator of standard error of regression)
My doubt is the following: 
In equation (10) , the last term  u bar, should be zero ? Because CLRM assumptions explicitly stated that E(u)= 0. Isn’t this equivalent to saying that u bar is 0? 
I’m confused.

Comment: The book is Basic Econometrics by DN Gujarati and Porter.

Answer (score 1):

Since your picture starts at eqn (10), most of the notations are undefined and we have to make a guess at them. I will thus assume this is a standard linear regression model where $(i=1,...,n)$ $$y_i=\beta_1+\beta_2 x_i + u_i$$and where the $u_i$ are iid with mean zero (0) and variance $\sigma^2$.

Second, it seems you are confusing sample empirical average with theoretical mean. Averaging the $n$ regression equations leads to eqn (10):
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \{\beta_1+\beta_2 x_i \} + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n u_i$$In this equation, the random variable$$\bar u = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n u_i$$has expectation zero but *is not zero* with probability $1$.

Comment: This is precisely what I haven’t understood. Since CLRM assumptions are on the PRF , isn’t the RHS of your last equation equal to E(u)? Which by assumption is 0 in a CLRM.

Comment: If possible then please elaborate or suggest a text that can help me

Comment: @ManasviSharma: Your textbook is called Basic Econometrics for a reason. If you cannot see the difference between a random variable and its expectation, you should try a Basic Probability textbook.